# How to output to console the format of the dataFrames in format("console")?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming

I'm doing the output of the `readStream` `format("rate")` and I'd like to get the format of the out of the box value field of the `dataframe`. The only option I have fount in the docs is `truncate`, but I can't find how to force to get something like that

```
Batch: 3
-------------------------------------------
+-----------------------+---------+
|timestamp:String       |value:Int|
+-----------------------+---------+
|2021-10-14 14:28:58.981|0        |
+-----------------------+---------+
```

instead of that

```
Batch: 3
-------------------------------------------
+-----------------------+-----+
|timestamp              |value|
+-----------------------+-----+
|2021-10-14 14:28:58.981|0    |
+-----------------------+-----+
```

Output code is:

```
df
      .writeStream
      .format("console")
      .option("truncate", "false")
      .start().awaitTermination(20000)
```

Comment: Don't think there is a function for this in spark's api. That said, you can achieve this by getting the schema from `dataframe.schema` and then use `select` with `as` along with the schema and column name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @m_vemuri

the solution is

```
println("Rate schema:")
println(rate.schema.fields.mkString)
```

and since that I know what is the type that `rate` produces for the `value`:

```
Rate schema:
StructField(timestamp,TimestampType,true)StructField(value,LongType,true)
```